# dynamically created table rows (jquery) not passing values on page postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have searched this problem and although it seems to be a common problem i have not been able to find a solution for my situation.
i have an asp:table control with one row on a page. a jquery script adds a new row on button click with a unique id. my problem is that on post back to add the values to the database, the additional rows do not exist after postback, just the initial one. 
so my question is how can i preserve the data from the dynamically created rows so that it can be passed to the codebehind.

the jquery function

```
 function addNewRow()
    {
        var i = 1;
        $("#<%=addRow.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $("#<%=tblAddItems.ClientID %> tr").eq(1).clone().find("input").each(function () {
                $(this).attr({
                    'id': function (_, id) { return id + i },
                    'name': function (_, name) { return name + i },
                    'value': ''
                });

                //  $(this).val('').attr('id', function (_, id) { return id + i });
                //}).end().appendTo("#<=tblAddItems.ClientID %>");
                // i++;
            }).end().appendTo("#<%=tblAddItems.ClientID %>");
            SearchItemNumber();
            i++;
        });

       }
```

the asp.net table

```
<asp:Table EnableViewState="true" runat="server" ID="tblAddItems" HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <asp:TableHeaderRow BackColor="#5C9CCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"
        VerticalAlign="Middle" TableSection="TableHeader"  Width="975px">
                     <asp:TableHeaderCell  style="display:none">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Item Id"></asp:Label>

                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>

                    <asp:TableHeaderCell >
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Item Number"></asp:Label>

                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>

                     <asp:TableHeaderCell >
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>

                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>

                     <asp:TableHeaderCell >
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="UOM"></asp:Label>

                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>

                     <asp:TableHeaderCell >
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="MPN"></asp:Label>

                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>

                     <asp:TableHeaderCell >
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Average Price"></asp:Label>

                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>

                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableRow TableSection="TableBody">

                      <asp:TableCell  style="display:none">
                       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="hdnItmDet" Height="12px" Width="150px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>  

                    <asp:TableCell style="display:none">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbItmId" Height="12px" Width="150px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbItmNo" Height="12px" Width="150px" CssClass="autosuggestItemDetails"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                     <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbDescription" Height="12px" Width="150px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                     <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbMPN" Height="12px" Width="150px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                        <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbUOM" Height="12px" Width="150px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                     <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbAvPrice" Height="12px" Width="150px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>


                       <asp:TableCell  style="display:none">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="hdnChanged" Height="12px" Width="150px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>   

                       <asp:TableCell  style="display:none">
                       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="hdnFlag1" Height="12px" Width="150px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>               

                </asp:TableRow>

         <asp:TableFooterRow TableSection="TableFooter">
             <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="1">
                 <button runat="server" ID="addRow" type="button">Add Row</button>
             </asp:TableCell>
             <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Add Items to List" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
             </asp:TableCell>
         </asp:TableFooterRow>
            </asp:Table>
```

and the buttons

```
<asp:Button ID="saveList" runat="server" Text="Save Changes to List" OnClick="saveList_Click" />
```

Comment: it would help to see the table html, and added jquery html

Comment: Are you using webforms?

Comment: @Jonesy thank you for your time i have updated the question with the code. and Becuzz yes i am using webforms.

Comment: everything works except that the saveList button only captures the first row and disregards any created rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to this is that since the controls were created client-side when you get back to the server it doesn't know how to map the form values.  You can get to the values through the Request.Form object like this:

```
string value = Request.Form["formElementName"];
```

Comment: this seems to be the solution but i am still having some issues with the value as the string remains null. upon debugging, i can see that Request.Form[tbItmNo.ClientID] contains the table values but it is not being assigned to the string.

Comment: i figured it out i had to use the exact client side id for it to work thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a hidden field in your asp.net behind code.
- Serialize your table to the field
- access the serialized code in the code behind and parse it again

Source:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1668471.aspx